# Formula to divide data from one cell equally into multiple cells

Tags: excel

I have these cells:

- Cell I7 where I put total hours a task will take, and
- Cell J7 has start time in yyww format, e.g. 1624, meaning year 2016 and week 24, and
- Cell K7 is the deadline in same format.

I have sequential week numbers in row 2, again in the same format, e.g.

- Cell L2 has 1622
- Cells on the right of L2 have incrementing week numbers: 1623, 1624,...

I want the total hours the task takes to be equally divided into the appropriate weeks. I am counting with the start week and the deadline week included. Use decimals if needed.

This sheet is only for 2016, meaning I don't go across year boundaries. For example:

Total time 100 hours. Start 1625, end 1634. Cell corresponding to column representing week 1625: 10 hours, week 1626: 10 hours, week 1627: 10 hours,... up to 10 weeks.

I want the hours divided into weeks to appear in the same row.
ex. I7=50 , J7=1601, K7=1605, L7=10, M7=10, N7=10, O7=10, P7=10.

[image]

Comment: You might want to clarify where you want the output to be appear: on the same row? Do you have specific columns for specific week numbers, or you just want to start filling in those hours in the first cell available? Note that if you have more lines which such tasks, and their start week is different, the calculated week hours that appear in the same column for those two tasks may not relate to the same week.... Please give an example of desired output (screenshot?) where you have at least two tasks.

Comment: Added an example showing how I mean ill add a screenshot aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a solution that would result in this output:

[image]

The input fields are located in cells I7, J7 and K7 like you described.

The formula in L7 expects the week number to appear in row 2:

```
=IF( AND(L$2>=$J7, L$2<=$K7), $I7/($K7-$J7+1), "")
```

That formula can be copied to the right and downward as far as you need it.

When some day you add weeks in row 2 for 2017, so you have a mix of 2016 and 2017 week numbers, then the above will fail for periods that cross the year boundary, since the denominator `($K7-$J7+1)` will return a too large number. If you want to deal with that, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(AND(L$2>=$J7,L$2<=$K7), $I7/(MATCH($K7,$2:$2;0)-MATCH($J7,$2:$2,0)+1), "")
```

That formula requires that the start- and end week really occur in row 2.

Note that your regional settings might be different for the list separator. In that case you might need to change the commas in the formula by semicolons (`;`). Regional settings also influence the names of the functions (`IF` and `AND`). Please check what the [Excel equivalent is in your language version](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/).

Comment: I dont want start date, end date and weeks. I know it would make it easier but this document cant have unnecessary information. I am also counting the first and last week meaning it should be divided into 11 weeks.

Comment: Then your first example in your question is wrong, because you divide 100 hours in chunks of 10. I will update my answer without the helper columns. It will make the formulas monstrous, but I guess you prefer it that way :)

Comment: Yes I noticed that, sorry

Comment: I added a picture, you can ignore line 3

Comment: Right, so the picture seems to suggest you have columns reserved for specific columns. I asked you about that you just said to fill the weeks in the adjacent columns. Now the question becomes different.... arghhh. Could you please add this requirement in your question? Note how important it is to be clear in your specifications.

Comment: You don't go across year boundaries? Please add that information also in your question.

Comment: I am soo sorry for being so unclear. This is my 2nd question ever asked. It got a bit complicated to explain the question since my first language isnt english. And no I dont go beyond year boundaries since this sheet is only for 2016. If it isnt hard to change so that it accepts year boundaries it would be fine too so I can reuse this for 2017 sheet. btw I am getting an error when I try your formula. It says " We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking instert function..... etc"

Comment: Excel is language-dependent, so formulas may need function names in local language, and may use other list separators. I provide the English version, as we cannot possibly cover all language versions in our answers. Put you can certainly find the regional equivalent via an internet search. I updated my answer based on the image you posted.

Comment: When there's no total task time it shows 0 in the cells in the calendars between the  start and end time, like this http://imgur.com/JNKqtNl . How can I make it blank instead or even better if possible make the weeks of which is concerned have a color so that it is easier to see which weeks the task concern. simplified question: How to make the 0 into a color instead.

Comment: Use [conditional formatting](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html).

Comment: Thanks again worked perfectly. I hope that question was a lot clearer :)

Comment: Would it be possible to have the values change if I where to manually change one of the equally divided numbers. Ex. total hours 154 weeks week number 1630-1640 divided into 14 each. I change 1 of the 14s into 16 and the other 14s automatically change to 13.9 so that the total stays the same

Comment: I am surprised to see you took back your acceptance of this answer. Is there an issue? Could you give some feed-back? As to your latest comment: yes that is possible, but that really is material for a new question. Could you ask it as a new question? You can post a link to it once you have it, and I will be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: This is my new question related to this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947446/nested-if-function-youve-entered-too-many-arguments-for-this-function

Comment: I had a look, but in the question you are asking two things at the same time, which is not good: your question will get closed because of the wrong number of arguments you have passed to the `IF`, and the second question *"Would it be possible to have the values in the calendar automatically change if I were to manually change one of the equally divided numbers"* will never be answered because of that. I think you should again post a new question, that focusses ***only*** on that last question.

Comment: Besides that, is there anything in this answer that is not answering your question here? What is the reason why you have retracted your acceptance after you said *"Thanks again worked perfectly"*?

Comment: I retracted the acceptance because I edited the question and that made the answer become incorrect ill mark it as answered again since I made that new post about the new question.

Comment: OK, maybe you can remove the edit from your question, as it is "not done" to add follow-up questions inside a question that already has answers. But thanks for having accepted again - I had put quite some time in it. In the mean time I have also answered your next question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a precise answer as the question is a little vague, but at the very least you need to break down the input into a more useable format that you can then reconstruct into the desired format.  For example, the following formula (adapted from [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6900) will convert "1625" into "12 June 2016":

```
=INT((DATE("20"&LEFT(B2,2),1,1)+(RIGHT(B2,2)*7)-7)/7)*7+1
```

Where cell B2 is the value 1625.  Do the same for the end date, then use the formula NETWORKDAYS() to work out the number of working days between these dates.  From that you can then work out the number of hours per day are needed, or whatever your requirements are.

If you can formulate the question a little more precisely I could probably give a more complete answer.  For example, are you trying to work out how many hours are needed per week to complete the task, or are you trying to estimate the manpower needed given, for example, 7 man-hours per day?