# Formula to auto change all calendar hours if I change 1 to keep the same total hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question is related to my other thread:
[Formula to divide data from one cell equally into multiple cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858428/formula-to-divide-data-from-one-cell-equally-into-multiple-cells/37859772?noredirect=1#comment63344985_37859772)

This is what I am trying to achieve:
Would it be possible to have the values in the calendar automatically change if I were to manually change one of the equally divided numbers.

Ex.

- Total hours 400
- Start week 1630
- end week 1630

Divided into 36 each I change 1 of the 36s into 100 and the other 36s automatically change to 30 so that the total stays 400.
This is how my excel sheet looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSbgj.jpg
The 3 columns to the left are

AQ4 =COUNTIF(L4:AP4;$I4/($K4-$J4+1))   ## This is the number of cells with the divided total

AR4 =SUM(L4:AP4)   ## this is the total value that I use to compare with the total hours it should take before I changed values manually

AS4 =COUNTIF(L4:AP4;"<>"&$I4/($K4-$J4+1))-COUNTIF(L4:AP4;"")   ## This is the number of cells that are not $I4/($K4-$J4+1) or blank.

This is what i've come up with this far but it is not working:

```
=IF(AND(AC$2>=$J4;AC$2<=$K4);$I4/($K4-$J4+1);AND($AS4>0;(2*$I4-$AR$4)/($AQ4-$AS4);($K4-$J4+1);$I4/($K4-$J4+1)))
```

Comment: The only way anyone could figure this out would be to paste it into Excel and play with it until they figure out which part is out of place.  Which is exactly what you should do.

Comment: Your outside `IF()` function call has 4 parameters. It should only have 3.

Comment: The IF function takes three arguments, you have 4.  I suspect you need to remove the first `"";`

Comment: You have too many semi-colons (arguments) in the first IF and no right parens in 2nd: `=IF(AND(Y$2>=$J4;Y$2<=$K4),$I4/($K4-$J4+1);IF(AQ4<>AS4;(2*I4-AR4)/(AS4-AQ4);$I4/($K4-$J4+1)))`

Comment: `=IF( AND(Y$2>=$J4; Y$2<=$K4); $I4/($K4-$J4+1); IF(aq4<>as4; (2*I4-AR4)/(AS4-AQ4; $I4/($K4-$J4+1)); ""))`

Comment: @FelixTorssell please mark an answer correct or be more specific in what you are trying to do

Comment: I added some information to my post, I hope that helps :)

Comment: The question risks to be closed soon because of the simple mistake in the `IF` that was spotted by @Phylogenesis. If this is not your issue, then please correct your question asap.

Comment: The formula I added at the top is my attempt at solving my issue, What my real question is, is the question asked under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859772/5459839) in your previous question, we have this formula in `L7`, which can be copied to other cells:

```
=IF( AND(L$2>=$J7; L$2<=$K7); $I7/($K7-$J7+1); "")
```

Now the challenge is to make that formula aware of the other values on the same row, as they might have been changed manually. This leads to a problem of circular reference: cell **L7** must take into account changes made to cell **M7**, but also **M7** should take into account changes made to cell **L7**. If there are (initially) no manually encoded values in either of these two cells, we have a circular reference. So this cannot be done.

However, what *can* be done, is to make the formula in each cell only look to its left side and make the calculation based on that. This way there will not be circular references.

This leads to the following formula for **L7**:

```
=IF(L$2=$J7; 
    $I7/($K7-$J7+1); 
    IF(AND(L$2>$J7; L$2<=$K7); 
       ($I7-SUM(OFFSET(L7;0;$J7-L$2;1;L$2-$J7)))/($K7-L$2+1); 
       ""))
```

This means:

If this cell is the first one of the period (`L$2=$J7`) then do as before, and calculate the evenly distributed value (`$I7/($K7-$J7+1)`). If this cell is another cell within the period, then take the sum of the previous cells (`SUM(OFFSET(L7;0;$J7-L$2;1;L$2-$J7))`), subtract that from the total required sum (`$I7-SUM(...)`) and divide that by the number of cells that remain on the right, counting this cell as well (`.../($K7-L$2+1)`). In all other cases output the empty string.

Copy this formula around.

Once you overwrite a value with a fixed number, you obviously destroy the formula that was there. But see how it makes the cells on the right of it recalculate. The sum remains constant. Be aware that changes in cells outside of the period are not taken into account.

Finally, make sure to make manual changes from left to right. If you make a change to a cell at the left of another cell that was already changed, things will no longer add up nicely. In that case, you first have to restore the formula in the righter cells, then make the change in the left cell, and then make again the changes in left-to-right order.

Comment: Thank You! I also came to that conclusion. I was thinking of doing it your way but couldn't figure out how to do it. I also like that you add explanations to your answers so I don't just copy paste it but also learn from it.

Comment: I just noticed something, if I add just the end date the cells show #REF!, Why is that?

Comment: and if start date is lower than the calendar supports I get error: Invalid cell reference.

Comment: For the first issue: indeed, this solution expects the start week to be filled in, otherwise it cannot know when the period starts and how many weeks there are in the period. You can suppress errors by wrapping the formula in a `IFERROR(........, "")`

Comment: For the second point: the start week must be present in the calendar, otherwise the formula cannot know which values were input for the hours in all of the preceding weeks in the period. If you want to get rid of older weeks in your calendar, consider hiding those columns instead of deleting them. That way the formulas keep working.

Comment: For an exact reason why you get the `#REF`: this is because of this part in  the formula: `OFFSET(L7;0;$J7-L$2;1;L$2-$J7))`. The third argument will find `$J7` to be zero (blank), and so that argument becomes a large negative value. This means `OFFSET` refers then to a cell with a negative column number, which results in `#REF`.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
=IF(AND(Y$2>=$J4,Y$2<=$K4),$I4/($K4-$J4+1),IF(AQ4<>AS4,(2*I4-AR4)/(AS4-AQ4),$I4/($K4-$J4+1)))
```

I don't know what you were trying to achieve but this function does not produce an error

your function had incorrect placing of arguments so it was like 2 separate if functions trying to be read in one cell, if you follow the guideline excel shows underneath the function while you're typing it this can be prevented in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
""; IF(aq4<>as4; (2*I4-AR4)/(AS4-AQ4; $I4/($K4-$J4+1))))
```

The "" is the If Not, after that is a fourth argument...